# java parallel (useful) packages

Tags: java, package, parallel-processing

I'm trying to get the best possible performance from my quad core cpus, and i just discovered Parallel Colt (matrix-related operations).

Do you know any other package that include useful "parallel" utils (es. spanning tree, sorting, so on...)

Answer (score 1):

you might want to take a look here:

[java.util.concurrent](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) that came with Java 5

Comment: I think he's looking for something more high-level than that

Comment: exactly, something more high-level will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't exactly an answer to your question, but you might be interested in Scala.  I believe utilizing many cores is one of the goals of Scala.

It also runs on the JVM so it interacts with java, is blazingly fast and contains all the new wizzy language features you might expect in a new language (and then some).

Comment: Scala is probably the highest level language around as far as new feature integration and stuff goes. More like a next gen language (ruby/etc) but with the speed and static type safety of Java. (Not that I'm a huge fan--I personally enjoy simplicity over power.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest a package called LeoTask: https://github.com/mleoking/leotask

It helps you conduct tasks and aggregate the results in parallel.